# CodeIgniter ZIP Add Data inaccurate

Tags: php, codeigniter

I was creating a monitor script using CI and make it downloadable. The files were generated by reading the file and modify the anchor pre-entered in the .ini and .php file.

But I found that the `strtr` part is not modified.

---

Part of the `controllers/monitor.php`:

```
$post    = $this->input->post();
$this->load->helper('file');
$monitor_php = read_file('script/monitor.php');
$monitor_php = str_replace(array('___MONITOR_CODE___'), array($monitor['monitor_code']),  $monitor_php);

$monitor_ini = read_file('script/monitor.ini');
$monitor_ini = strtr($monitor_ini, $post);
$monitor_ini = str_replace(array('___MONITOR_HOST___'    , '___MONITOR_SCRIPT___'    , '___MONITOR_REPORT_INTERVAL___'),
                              array($monitor['monitor_host'], $monitor['monitor_script'], $monitor['monitor_report_erval']),
                              $monitor_ini);

$this->load->library('zip');
$this->zip->add_data('monitor.php', $monitor_php);
$this->zip->add_data('monitor.ini', $monitor_ini);
$this->zip->download('monitor');
```

---

The result of `var_export($post);`:

```
array (
  '___OPERATING_SYSTEM___' => 'CentOS 7.2',
  '___WEB_SERVICE___' => 'httpd',
  '___MYSQL_SERVICE___' => 'mariadb'
)
```

---

I have `echo` the `$ping_ini` and it appears to be fine, but the file is still nothing changed.

The result of `echo $monitor_ini;`:

```
[Analyser]
MonitorHost = "localhost"
MonitorScript = "monitor.php"
OperatingSystem = "CentOS 7.2" // Good
ReportInterval = "1800"

[Service]
WebService = "httpd" // Good
MySQLService = "mariadb" // Good
```

But actually the downloaded `monitor.ini` is:

```
[Analyser]
MonitorHost = "localhost"
MonitorScript = "monitor.php"
OperatingSystem = "___OPERATING_SYSTEM___" // nothing changed
ReportInterval = "1800"

[Service]
WebService = "___WEB_SERVICE___" // nothing changed
MySQLService = "___MYSQL_SERVICE___" // nothing changed
```

Comment: I did a mockup of your ini file, $post (from your var_export) and $monitor data from what you provided! So under those conditions it works. I can't see how your Post data isn't working from what you have said. So I don't know. Something else is going on here. In your monitor.ini file are you sure those values do have 3 leading and trailing underscores?

Comment: Yes because when I `echo` the whole `$monitor_ini` in string, it does replaced with the information I gave.